# avoidng just one match labels in match function in R

Tags: r, vector, matching

I have two vectors

```
v1<-c("T","A","G","R","A","G")
v2<-c("R","A","G,"T","A","G")
```

i want to find the longest matching subsequence. what i did is

```
 v<-match(v1,v2)
```

> v
> [1] 4 2 3 1 2 3

expected output:

> v
> [1] NA 2 3 NA 2 3

the longest should be 2 3 in either location corresponding to the "A" "G" but the match function labels the "T" in v2 as 1 in the match, so the longest match subsequence end up being 1 2 3 and thats not what i want

any help please ? is there a way to let match function have like a minimum match before it starts labeling

Comment: What is the expected output

Comment: v [1] NA 2 3 NA 2 3

Comment: Why the longest subsequence is not 1 2 3 for last 3 values? I am not sure if I understand your question, can you create few more examples with expected output?

Comment: oh yes thank you so much LCS was a nice function. @RonakShah so if you look back at the dna strings you find that AG is the longest common substring but the match function messes up by putting 1 referring to the T in the first string